# In GraphQL, how can I elegantly define increasingly scoped queries?

Tags: graphql

Suppose I have a domain like this:

```
type ProductSku {
  id: ID!
  name: String
}

type ProductLine {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  productSkus: [ProductSku]
}

type Manufacturer {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  productLines: [ProductLine]
}
```

In my website, I have routes like this:

- `/` - A list of all manufacturers
- `/apple` - Information about `Manufacturer` `apple`
- `/apple/iphone-11/` - Information about `ProductLine` `iphone-11` under `apple`
- `/apple/iphone-11/64gb-black` - Information about `ProductSku` `64gb-black` under `iphone-11`, under `apple`

I am having trouble designing the `Query` type for my GraphQL server.

I started with just this:

```
type Query {
  manufacturers: [Manufacturer]
}
```

This gives me all of the data, so it does the job. However, it is inefficient for the nested routes, since I discard most of the data client-side.

Alternatively, I can define a query for each route:

```
type Query {
  manufacturers: [Manufacturer]
  manufacturer(manufacturerId: ID): Manufacturer
  productLine(manufacturerId: ID, productLineId: ID): ProductLine
  productSku(manufacturerId: ID, productLineId: ID, productSkuId: ID): ProductSku
}
```

But this seems very verbose.

How should I approach this?

---

Note that the IDs are only unique within the space of the parent. For example, there might be two product lines containing a product SKU `black-64gb`. This is because they are actually slugs from the URL.

Comment: whats verbose about it?

Comment: Well I've already defined how to resolve a `Manufacturer`, so it seems odd that I need to do it again to fetch a `ProductLine` for a `Manufacturer`

Comment: why don't you keep the query for `ProductLine` more generic and just accept a `productLineId` & let the resolvers for `Manufacturer.productLines` handle the relationship between the two?